# How to interrupt an xQueueReceive() API in FreeRTOS?

Tags: task, message-queue, rtos, freertos

In the following code

- `SendMessage()` is the API called by the user to send a message over USB
- `UsbDataReceived()` is the function called by another thread when data is received on the USB
- `Task()` is the thread created in `init()` that reads from the queue filled by `SendMessage()` and calls the low level usb function to send a message
- `UsbConnected()` is the function called by another thread when a USB device is connected.

I need to implement the following behaviour:

- Once a message has been sent, no new messages can be sent up to when an answer for the last message has arrived
- When `UsbConnected()` is called, all of the queues must be emptied and if the thread `Task()` is waiting on the queue `AnswerQueue`, it has to be unblocked so that it can go back to wait on the queue `CommandQueue`

An example of my best solution is listed below.

I had to post an `EVENT_QUEUE_RESETTED` message on both of the queues with a particular order.

Is it possible to achieve the same result in a less cumbersome way?

```
void UsbhOut(Message_t );
int UsbConnected;
QueueHandle_t MessageQueue;



typedef enum
{
    EVENT_QUEUE_RESETTED,
    EVENT_NEW_MESSAGE,
    EVENT_NEW_ANSWER,
} Event_t;

typedef struct
{
    Event_t Event;
    uint8_t Data[32];
} CommandQueue_t;

typedef struct
{
    Event_t Event;
    uint8_t Data[32];
} AnswerQueue_t;


void init(void)
{
  MessageQueue = xQueueCreate(sizeof(Message_t), 10);
  AnswerQueue = xQueueCreate(sizeof(Message_t), 10);
  xTaskCreate(Task, "", 200, NULL, 1, NULL);
}

void UsbConnected(void)
{
  CommandEvent.Event = EVENT_QUEUE_RESETTED;
  AnswerEvent.Event = EVENT_QUEUE_RESETTED;

  UsbConnected = 1;
  xQueueReset(MessageQueue);
  xQueueReset(AnswerQueue);

  /* The order here is fundmental */
  xQueueSend(AnswerQueue, &AnswerEvent, 0);
  xQueueSend(MessageQeueue, &CommandEvent, 0);

}


int SendMessage(uint8_t * Data)
{
  CommandQueue_t CommandEvent;

  CommandEvent.Event = EVENT_NEW_MESSAGE;
  memcpy(&CommandEvent, Message, 32);

  if(xQueueSend(MessageQueue, &CommandEvent, 0) == pdTRUE)
    return 0;
  else
    return -1;
}


void UsbDataReceived(uint8_t * Data)
{
  AnswerQueue_t AnswerEvent;
  AnswerEvent.Event = EVENT_NEW_ANSWER;
  memcpy(AnswerEvent.Data, Data, 32);

  xQueueSend(AnswerQueue, &AnswerEvent,0);
}


void Task(void *pvParameters)
{
  CommandQueue_t CommandEvent;
  AnswerQueue_t AnswerEvent;
  CommandCallback_t * Callback;

  while(1)
  {
     xQueueReceive(UsbhStaticData.CommandSenderQueue, &CommandEvent, portMAX_DELAY);

     if(CommandEvent.Event == CommandSenderQueueData_t::EVENT_QUEUE_RESETTED)
     {
       continue;
     }

     /* Low level Usb fucntion used to send Data */
     UsbdSendData(Command.Data);

     xQueueReceive(UsbhStaticData.AnswerReceivdQueue, &AnswerEvent, portMAX_DELAY);

     if(AnswerEvent.Event == AnswerReceivedQueueData_t::EVENT_QUEUE_RESETTED)
     {
         continue;
     }
     else if(AnswerEvent.Event == AnswerReceivedQueueData_t::EVENT_ANSWER_RECEIVED)
     {
       ParseData(AnswerEvent.Data);
     }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Queue Sets
[FreeRTOS Queue Set API](http://www.freertos.org/RTOS-queue-sets.html)
That way you could create a Queue Set containing a queue and a semaphore. Your task would block on the Queue Set. It would then get unblocked by either receiving a message from the queue or you incrementing the semaphore.